# Error in running ubuntu's Quickly app. in root

Tags: ubuntu, schema, gnome, canonical-quickly

I had made a GUI for my project using Ubuntu's **Quickly**. When I run the app in root using command `quickly run`, I get the following error

> GLib-GIO-ERROR *: Settings schema 'org.gnome.desktop.interface' is not
>   installed".

However the app runs fine when it is not in root. But my project further requires to open a device, which fails if it is not in root.

So my problem here is to remove the above error while running **Quickly** app in root.

Any advice would be very helpful.

Comment: can you run it via sudo/gksu/gksudo ?

Comment: Adding a comment because strictly speaking I'm not answering the question: the right way to solve your actual problem is probably to define  udev rule that sets the permissions of the device appropriately (maybe giving permissions to a specific group) instead of running a GUI app as root.